# Getting started with fusion table maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I have created a fusion table with data for a number for counties. This data looks something like this:

```
County  Boundary    Democrat    Republican  PercentageMen   AverageAge
1       kml         41          46          53              55
2       ...
```

How would you recommend I produce maps based on this data?

For example I want a gradient-shaded map showing the percentage voting democrat. 
I also want a map showing those counties that voted Republican where the average age is under 45, etc.

I then wish to show all these maps on a single web page.

Please direct me towards the relevant documentation and any relevant online examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to show the data on a map, I would use the [FusionTablesLayers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers?#FusionTables). They are part of the Google Maps API and are designed to show data from Fusion Tables on Google Maps.

To get the basic idea, you can use the [FusionTablesLayer Wizard](http://fusion-tables-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FusionTablesLayerWizard/src/index.html), which gives you a skeleton to work with. Once you have your data on the map, you can start to style it. There are [various options available to change the look](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers?#fusion_table_styles) of your polygons/lines/markers ([see this example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-fusiontables-styling)). By specifying the `where`-Clause of a style, you can change the styling based on your data (e.g. average age).

Just remember that there is a limitation from Fusion Tables to 5 styling rules.